# How to capture request in Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, actiondispatch

I need to conditionally set the `param` option in routes.

Without condition it's easy:

```
resources :foo, param: :uuid do
  #...
end
```

What I ideally want is something along the following lines (not working obviously):

```
resources :foo, param: ->(req) { req.env['PATH_INFO'].match?(/bar/) ? :uuid : :id } do
  #...
end
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Just to change the param key to `uuid`?  I would stick with `:id` and handle it by using a special finder like friendly_id does.

Comment: @max I installed friendly_id, but only for few controllers I need to use `param: :slug`. In other controllers this resource should stay unchanged using default `param`...

Comment: Can you use a constraint? `resources :foo, constraints: lambda { |req| req.env['PATH_INFO'].match?(/bar/) }`

Comment: @Iceman constraint is something totally different from what I need. Constraints restrict access to resource based on something, I need not to restrict access but to conditionally set `param` option.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What my suggestion was, is to include two `resources` lines in the `routes.rb` file, one which matches and one that does not. And set your param that way.

Comment: @Iceman yea, this is one of the options I first thought of. But i will have to repeat about 90 lines of code because of that... :\ So it's the last resort option and I'd rather never use it.

Comment: Ok, I see, that's a bit too much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write a piece of middleware that alters the params:

```
class ParamTransformer
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env['PATH_INFO'].match?(/bar/)
      env.request.update_param('slug', env.request.params['id'])
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

# config/application.rb
config.middleware.use 'ParamTransformer'
```

If you really want to do it conditionally on your routes you could create a constraint:

```
class ParamTransformerConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    if env['PATH_INFO'].match?(/bar/)
      request.update_param('slug', request.params['id'])
    end
    true # lets everyone through
  end
end
```

It feels really hacky though.

Comment: the problem with "normalizing the routes to use `:id`" is that I'd have to change code it super to many places when it comes to `friendly_id`. So I wanted to limit the code change to just the controller/views where I want to use `:slug` and leave it as is everywhere else..

Comment: Ok then just use middleware.

Comment: Hm, I don't have access to `request` variable there (it's undefined)

Comment: My bad - it should be `env.request`

Comment: You might need to use `rake middleware` to inspect the middleware stack and insert_after to get it in the right position.

Comment: `env.request` is undefined as well, because `env` is simply an instance of `Hash`.